# Django REST - cannot create model with relationships

Tags: python, django, rest, relationship, serialization

I created a code for my related models:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    # Basic
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    # Enums
    GOALKEEPER = 'GOALKEEPER'
    DEFENDER = 'DEFENDER'
    MIDFIELDER = 'MIDFIELDER'
    FORWARD = 'FORWARD'
    POSITION = (
        (GOALKEEPER, 'Goalkeeper'),
        (DEFENDER, 'Defender'),
        (MIDFIELDER, 'Midfielder'),
        (FORWARD, 'Forward')
    )
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=POSITION, default=GOALKEEPER)

class PlayerDetail(models.Model):
    # Basic
    height = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    # Relationships
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='player_detail')
```

Then, I have done a serializers for every model:

```
class PlayerDetailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerDetail
        fields = ('weight', 'height')


class PlayerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    player_detail = PlayerDetailSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'position', 'player_detail')
```

My `create` method in `views.py` looks like this:

```
   def create(self, request):
        serializer = PlayerSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response('Player cannot be created', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Well, I send a JSON request to this simple API. The object I send is:

```
 {
        "first_name": "Player1",
        "last_name": "Player1",
        "position": "DEFENDER",
        "player_detail": {
             "weight": 80,
              "height": 180
        }
}
```

In result I only see 400 bad request and `Player cannot be created`. I don't know why it is wrong. I think my relationship is define good.
What is a good way to create connected objects via JSON?

**EDIT:**
Now my serializer looks like:

```
class PlayerDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerDetail
        fields = ('weight', 'height')


class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    player_detail = PlayerDetailSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'position', 'player_detail')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        player_detail = validated_data.pop('player_detail')
        player = Player.objects.create(**validated_data)
        PlayerDetail.objects.create(player=player, **player_detail)
        return player
```

but still I get this error:
`{'player_detail': {'non_field_errors': ['Expected a list of items but got type "dict".']}}`

I also try to do it without `many=True` in `PlayerDetailSerializer` then `serializer.save()` is called but I get an `return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.IntegrityError` with empty column value in `player_detail_id`.

**EDIT 2:**
I've solved this. I have changed a `create` method in serializer to this:

```
  def create(self, validated_data):
        player_detail = PlayerDetail.objects.create(**validated_data.pop('player_detail'))
        player = Player.objects.create(player_detail=player_detail, **validated_data)
        return player
```

and now object with nested reliationship has been created.

Comment: If it's a validation error in the serializer, you'll find what's wrong in serializer.errors.

Also, check out how to create the related objects, if have the feeling that you are not creating the nested objects correctly, read here: [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

Comment: @DA-- - I get an error in serializers.errors: `Expected a list of items but got type "dict"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `create` method is in the `PlayerDetailSerializer`? Note that it takes the validated data as an argument, you're passing the request.

Also, you have to pop the `PlayerDetail` "manually", and create the model instance. Because you don't do this, the dict is in the validated data as the Player is validated. Then pass the object key to the `Player.objects.create` method . I cannot explain it better than the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers), but I'll paste the `create` method from the documentation as I think that's what you have to change.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    tracks_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
    album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for track_data in tracks_data:
        Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)
    return album
```

Please let me know if I misunderstood your problem, so i can edit this answer.

Comment: `create` method is in the views.py

Comment: Well, than add a create method to the serializer :)

Comment: I edited my post. I added method you said, but I think it didn't help.

Comment: Finally, I have solved this problem. I needed to change some code in `create` method in serializer. Thanks for help.

Comment: This is not working for me, no matter what I send in 'tracks' I am getting []